# updating millions of rows in multiple tables sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where I am going to need to update millions of rows in 11 different tables. I only have to update 1 column in each of the tables but I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to do this? One thought was to drop the indexes on the tables temporarily and run update statements in batches of 100,000 on 1 table at a time. We are planning to take the database offline to prevent potential locking issues. I would like to know what the fastest way to update all of these tables would be. Our database is Microsoft SQL Server 2005. Below are the counts of rows from the 11 tables that need updated.

```
Table 1 206,108

Table 2 560,859

Table 3 690,946

Table 4 1,106,173

Table 5 3,159,963

Table 6 3,250,619

Table 7 4,046,048

Table 8 5,638,351

Table 9 8,880,814

Table 10 18,060,095

Table 11 76,294,745
```

Comment: Execution time is critical as this is a critical application to the enterprise so I really want to minimize the time it takes to run which is why I'm asking what the best way is to update all of these rows in the fastest manner.

Comment: You need to update every row in every table? This doesn't smell right to me.

Comment: Yes we do we are changing vendors and we have to update these tables to use there new identification number

Comment: So you need the same identification number in every single row of every single table? You haven't made this smell any better.

Comment: It's not the same identification number, it's an identification number that represents a unique item. So for example 1 item might be old123 and another would be old456 and the new item number would be new123 and new456 so what I need to do is for these tables update old123 to new123 and so on. These 11 tables are not all of our tables just the ones that use this item number.

Answer (score 2):

*Most efficient* is a fuzzy term. You're talking about updating about 122 million rows. If you start running naive updates now, it will probably finish before you can create a useful estimate. (I'd expect it to take about half an hour on my development machine. Updating 50 million rows takes 12 minutes.)

Dropping indexes beforehand is fine *if* you have your DDL under version control, and you can rebuild the indexes more or less automatically. Dropping *all* constraints should make the updates run faster still, but again I'd do that *only* if

- execution time were critical,
- DDL were under version control, and
- I could rebuild all the constraints more or less automatically.

Cascading foreign key constraints can be an issue.

Personally, I try to avoid situations where execution time is critical. I don't usually drop primary key and foreign key constraints. And I always rehearse outside the maintenance window.